# Project module imports - Python2.7 [Beginner]

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, wxpython, wxwidgets

Its my first project in Python and for some reason I cannot import a module i made from the root directory of my project.

The project structure is as follows

- Project

  - ui

    - **init**.py
    - MainWindow.py
  - main.py

And in main.py I'm trying to import a class from MainWindow.py as:

```
# Python
import sys

# ui
import wx

# Own files
import ui.MainWindow


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    MainWindow(None, title="Internet HW")
    app.MainLoop()


main()
```

But I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named ui.MainWindow

MainWindow.py:

```
# UI
import wx


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(600, 600))

    def InitUI(self):
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
```

I understand this is a newbie question but I cannot cope with it from what I've read. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason your code would not work as shown.

From the command line you can run `python -c "import ui; print dir(ui);"` and it will show you all of the objects available in the **ui** module.

- If that command errors, there is likely a permissions problem on your subfolder. It could also be an issue with one of the precompiled **.pyc** files - try deleting all of them in your Project and ui folders.
- If it only shows builtin functions like `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`, there may be an issue with your `__init__.py` file in the **ui** module.
- If it shows objects you do not recognize, there may be some other **ui** module installed that is being imported. Try changing the name of your module to **myui** or something similar and importing from there.